# how to calc the top point of a sphere in opengl?

Tags: opengl, graphics, jogl

After

```
gl.glRotate(45,0,0,1)
gl.glScaled(0,2,0)// 
glut.glutSolidSphere(1, 10, 20);
```

The top point of a sphere should be (-2*sin45,2*sin45,0)

But I calc it by myself.

Does the opengl has functions to calc special points of sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is a drawing API, not a math library. In fact those poor substitute for a matrix math library found in legacy OpenGL (glRotate, glTranslate, glScale) have been removed from modern OpenGL. So if you got the skills and abilities to calculate it yourself: Way to go. OpenGL is not the right tool to do this job.